# Calulate the differences between each element of two lists

Tags: python, list

I would like to calculate the difference of each entry of a list from each element of another list. Considering two lists A and B

```
A = [1,2,3,4] B=[5,6,7]
```

a new list c should have 12 entries

```
C=[1-5,1-6,1-7,2-5,2-6,2-7,....,4-7]
C=[-4,-5,-6,-3,-4,-5,....,-3]
```

Of course this is possible with loops, but is there a faster and more efficient way? My lists A and B have the dimensions 8000 and 2500, and I have to do it about 150 times in a row.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to use loops. If you need the difference between the cartesian product over every element in a list, there's no way around iterating over every pair in the cartesian product...

Comment: A calculation is a calculation. I think you're stuck with looping here.

Comment: You could try numpy for speeding things up, but you'll still need to access and perform a calculation on each possible pair. `[i-j for i in A for j in B]` is probably your most elegant option.

Comment: if you consider numpy , we do not need for loop here, btw, do you accept numpy solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `repeat` and `tile` from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

np.repeat(A,len(B))-np.tile(B,len(A))
Out[221]: array([-4, -5, -6, -3, -4, -5, -2, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3])
```

Comment: @user9115313 yW:-) , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can try in one line without importing any module :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y:(x-y),b)),a)))
```

output:

```
[[-4, -5, -6], [-3, -4, -5], [-2, -3, -4], [-1, -2, -3]]
```

or using list comprehension :

```
print([(i-j) for i in a for j in b])
```

output:

```
[-4, -5, -6, -3, -4, -5, -2, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3]
```